# How to take Screen Shot in Particular Area in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using **Unity 2018**. In my project i have to take  particular area screen. I have using the below code. It is working. But The exact image is not working. It goes some extent. How can i take the exact image.

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using System;

  public class ScreenCapture : MonoBehaviour
  {
  public RenderTexture overviewTexture;
  GameObject OVcamera;
  public string path = "";

  void Start()
  {
  OVcamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("OverviewCamera");
  }
  void LateUpdate()
 {           
 if (Input.GetKeyDown("f9"))
 {
 StartCoroutine(TakeScreenShot());
 }    
 }
// return file name
 string fileName(int width, int height)
{
 return string.Format("screen_{0}x{1}_{2}.png",
 width, height,
 System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
 }

 public IEnumerator TakeScreenShot()
 {
 yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

 Camera camOV = OVcamera.camera;  
 RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;    
 RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
 camOV.Render();
 Texture2D imageOverview = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, 
 TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
 imageOverview.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 
 0);
 imageOverview.Apply();
 RenderTexture.active = currentRT;           
 byte[] bytes = imageOverview.EncodeToPNG();

     // save in memory
 string filename = fileName(Convert.ToInt32(imageOverview.width), 
 Convert.ToInt32(imageOverview.height));
 path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Snapshots/" + filename;       
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
 }
 }
```

this is my above code..

Answer (score 0):

**use  this:**

```
    Texture2D screencap;
    Texture2D border;
    bool shot=false;
    public string path;

    void Start () {
         screencap=new Texture2D(300,200,TextureFormat.RGB24,false);
         border=new Texture2D(2,2,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
         border.Apply();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            StartCoroutine("Capture");
        }

    }
    string fileName(int width, int height)
    {
        return string.Format("screen_{0}x{1}_{2}.png",
                             width, height,
                             System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(200,100,300,2),border,ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(200,300,300,2),border,ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(195,100,2,200),border,ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(500,100,2,201),border,ScaleMode.StretchToFill);

        if(shot)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(50,10,60,40),screencap,ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
            //Application.CaptureScreenshot(myFolderLocation+myFilename);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Capture()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        screencap.ReadPixels(new Rect(198,98,298,198),0,0);
        screencap.Apply();
        shot=true;

        byte[] bytes=border.EncodeToPNG();
        string filename=fileName(Convert.ToInt32(screencap.width), Convert.ToInt32(screencap.height));
        Application.CaptureScreenshot("D:"+filename);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your coding. Entire screen is capturing... it is not capturing the desired  size. Any idea ...

Answer (score 0):

This script takes customised screeenshot of any Object that has RectTransform component attached to it.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TakeScreenshotAndSave : MonoBehaviour
{
//Object To Screenshot
[SerializeField] private RectTransform _objToScreenshot;

//Assign the button to take screenshot on clicking
[SerializeField] private Button _takeScreenshotButton;

void Start()
{
    
_takeScreenshotButton.onClick.AddListener(OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton);
}

private void OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(TakeSnapShotAndSave());
}

//Using a Coroutine instead of normal method
public IEnumerator TakeSnapShotAndSave()
{
    //Code will throw error at runtime if this is removed
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    //Get the corners of RectTransform rect and store it in a array vector
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    _objToScreenshot.GetWorldCorners(corners);

    //Remove 100 and you will get error
    int width = ((int)corners[3].x - (int)corners[0].x) - 100;
    int height = (int)corners[1].y - (int)corners[0].y;
    var startX = corners[0].x;
    var startY = corners[0].y;

    //Make a temporary texture and read pixels from it
    Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
    ss.Apply();

    Debug.Log("Start X : " + startX + " Start Y : " + startY);
    Debug.Log("Screen Width : " + Screen.width + " Screen Height : " + 
    Screen.height);
    Debug.Log("Texture Width : " + width + " Texture Height : " + height);

    //Save the screenshot to disk
    byte[] byteArray = ss.EncodeToPNG();
    string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ScreenshotSave.png";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, byteArray);
    Debug.Log("Screenshot Path : " + savePath);

    // Destroy texture to avoid memory leaks
    Destroy(ss);
}
}
```